# Open-api-generator generates List<Flux<FilePart>> instead of Flux<FilePart>

Tags: spring-boot, openapi-generator

We are using open-api-generator Maven plugin in a spring-boot webflux application in order to generate DTOs and controllers from an openapi specification.

We are using:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>openapi-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>7.2.0</version>
</plugin>
```

When we try:

```
  ...
  requestBody:
    required: true
    content:
      multipart/form-data:
        schema:
          type: object
          properties:
            files:
              type: array
              items:
                type: string
                format: binary
  ...
```

We get:

```
@Parameter(name = "files") @RequestPart(value = "files") List<Flux<Part>> files,
```

Instead of:

```
@Parameter(name = "files") @RequestPart(value = "files") Flux<Part> files,
```